# Arbitrary Key Remapping on a Mac

Tags: mac

I bought a cheap Chinese replacement keyboard for my late 2007 MBP.  The close square/curly bracket key actually sends a left control signal to the Mac.  So I'm trying to remap my backslash/pipe key to be close square/curly bracket but I can't find the key remapping software to do it.  Double Command and KeyRemap4Macbook can't do arbitrary key remaps and uControl/fkeys don't work on Snow Leopard.  Anyone have ideas?  I have no problem editing text config files if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) to create your own keyboard layout.

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom settings in KeyRemap4MacBook by creating a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en). Try something like this:

```
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CONTROL_R, KeyCode::BRACKET_RIGHT</autogen>
```

See my website for more information about KeyRemap4MacBook, custom keyboard layouts, and DefaultKeyBinding.dict:

http://osxnotes.net/keyremap4macbook.html
http://osxnotes.net/keylayout-files-and-ukelele.html
http://osxnotes.net/keybindings.html

Comment: Yeah - I left the close square bracket key as-is and reassigned the backslash/pipe key.  As far as the laptop is concerned, the close square bracket key is a physical left control key.

Comment: @Lri - second link is broken

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [karabiner](http://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner)
You can remap all keys as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this method](http://randomfoo.net/blog/id/4092) of using applescript to map keys differently.

Comment: It just opens the Keyboard preference pane in system preferences, where the assignment of modifier keys can be changed. That person's problem is that he wants to switch the setting regularly, therefore uses GUI scripting. That dialog is far from "arbitrary key remaps" though.

Answer (score 0):

[KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/document.html) might be useful as well.

Comment: My post specifically states that it does not work for what I'm doing.